# Adding more than one character using ManuelBastioniLab

Tags: manuel-bastioni-lab

is there a way to create more than one character in the same scene by using MBLab? When I create the first one I do not not have the "Create Character " available anymore. I need to add more than one character and they need to have active pose as they need to be set accordingly.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it in a new .blend file, It is possible but I had to "Finalize" the first character created, and the second one was still editable.

Have you tried to create a .blend file per character and append them in a main scene file ? This way you can still play individually with your character and have full control of your scene.

Comment: No did not try! I will :D